# pull everything from db and then compute stats?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an auto trade website. On the page where Ad list gets displayed, I plan to display the number of Ad for different categories: for example, for location: I will display something like "Vancouver (50), Richmond (12), Surrey (20)". For vehicle make, the following will be shown "Honda (20), Ford(12), VW (24)".

I am not sure if I should pull ALL the ad from the db into a List first, bind one page of the result to gridview control, and then compute stats for each category using Linq. if course I will limit the number of rows pulled from the db using some kind of condition - maybe set the MAX # of rows to be returned as 500.

My major concern is - is this going to be a memory hog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad idea to count rows in the memory. Use

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM... [ GROUP BY ]
```

which is much more efficient.

Also review possibility to cache these values. Assuming that multiple people loads your page simultaneously, but count of cars don't changes quicker then once per 1 minute - apply caching strategy to obsolete values over 1 min.

Comment: Considering the language the OP use, I think you should give a complete-ish SQL query rather than pseudocode.

Comment: what if I need to do COUNT on multiple groups (Location, Make, etc...) issue multiple SELECT won't be a problem? I am concerned of performance mostly. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @sean717 - we have some measurement about similar issue, actually execute multiple queries (Location, Make in you case) is much efficient than extract all records to client side, and count it. 
And don't forget to cache these results.